# Drop Down ComboBox

Tags: java, swing

My ComboBox having many string objects let's say for an instance ("David", "John", "Mary", "Gabriel", "Anderson", "Henry","Johnson", "Halstead", "Annie", "Jubilee").
ComboBox is editable.
so, whatever I write in comboBox, in dropdown option I should get only string objects that get matched with the string typed in comboBox.
Let's say,If I have typed "An" in Combobox field then I should have only Annie and Anderson in ComboBox list.A

```
public void setEditor(ComboBoxEditor editor){
    super.setEditor(editor);
    setEditable(true);
     if (editor.getEditorComponent() instanceof JTextField) {
         inputField = (JTextField) editor.getEditorComponent();
         inputField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
             char key = e.getKeyChar();
             String[] matchedString;
             if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(key)||Character.isSpaceChar(key)||key=='\b'){
                 if(key=='\b'){
                    matchedString = getMatchedItems(inputField.getText());
                    removeAllItems();
                    for(int i=0; i<matchedString.length; i++){
                        addItem(matchedString[i]);
                    }
                 }
                    
                 
                 else{
                     matchedString = getMatchedItems(inputField.getText()+key);
                     removeAllItems();
                        for(int i=0; i<matchedString.length; i++){
                            addItem(matchedString[i]);
                        }
                 }
             }
            
         }

        private int getMatchedCount(String currentWord) {
            int n = getItemCount(),count=0;
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                if(((String)getItemAt(i)).toLowerCase().startsWith(currentWord.toLowerCase())){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
        
        private String[] getMatchedItems(String currentWord){
            int n = getItemCount(),k=0;
            String[] matchedString = new String[getMatchedCount(currentWord)];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(((String)getItemAt(i)).toLowerCase().startsWith(currentWord.toLowerCase())){
                    matchedString[k++] = (String)getItemAt(i);
                }
            }
            return matchedString;
        }
    });
     }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame fr=new JFrame();
    fr.setLayout(null);
    /*List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Shahroz");
    list.add("Wasif");
    list.add("Akram");
    */
    String str[] = {"Shahroz","saleem","Khan","Wasif","Dutta","Piyush","Rajat","Rehan","Rajesh"}; 
    fr.add(new AutoCombo(str));
    fr.setSize(400, 800);
    fr.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: But what is the question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is code-writing-request without any description of problem which is stopping OP from writing it him/herself.

Answer (score 2):

> This is different from AutoCompleteComboBox.

Maybe, but the concept is the same.

Every time a character is typed in the combo box you do something. In this case the something that you do is search the list of entries and only add the valid ones to the model of the combo box.

So you need to add a `DocumentListener` to the editor of the combo box. Then whenever a DocumentEvent is fired you get the current value from the editor of the combo box. Then you clear all the items in the combobox. Finally you search the list of items and add the matching items to the combo box.

Edit:

To Access text field used as the editor you just use:

```
ComboBoxEditor editor = combobox.getEditor();
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getEditorComponent();
// add the DocumentListener to the Document
```

Comment: Please see above code... Can't I add keyListener to the field of comboBox (inputField here)?

Comment: @ShahrozSaleem The suggestion was to use a `DocumentListener`, not a KeyListener. There is no need to extend the combo box you can access the text field directly. See edit.